# Converting a regular Maven project to a Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

My supervisor asked me to convert an old Maven project we have lying around into a Spring Boot project such that we are able to access the project's backend via RESTful interaction (before that the project's backend was only accessible via a console interface).

So, first I added a simple Spring Boot application in a separate package of project. After that I began to extend the pom.xml of the project by the dependencies needed for Spring Boot and adjusted the overall project setup. Now, I tried to run the backend of the old project, which turned out to be working. However, the simple Spring Boot application did not.

I narrowed down the problem to a conflicting dependency in the "old" part of the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I leave this dependency in the pom.xml the old backend works, but the Spring Boot application fails with the following error:

```
WARN: Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

If I comment this dependency out the Spring Application works completely fine, but the old backend fails. I use the version `2.0.4.RELEASE` of `spring-boot-admin-starter-server`. I think that the old backend's version of the logging package is different from the one included in `spring-boot-admin-starter-server`. However, I somehow need both versions in my project.

What's not possible:

- Updating the old sources, since some of them have a coyright of an
  external company

What I already tried, but I wasn't successful with:

- Exclude the logging from then Spring Boot depedencies. This results in the following error:

`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`

- I also to tried to work with the shade plugin as some suggested from my web research. Unfortunately, I was not able to solve the problem with this approach.

Does anyone have suggestions how to solve this problem? I would be very grateful. I am not used to solve dependency problems of this kind. Please excuse me, if I am missing something obvious.

-lema

> EDIT pom.xml (unfortunately I had to leave out bigger parts of it) :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

... 

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description></description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot-admin.version>2.0.2</spring-boot-admin.version>
    <spring-boot-dependencies.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring-boot-dependencies.version>

    ...

    <rat.skip>true</rat.skip>
    <log4j-version>2.6.1</log4j-version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    ...
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Necessary dependency for running Spring Boot without starter parent -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Fowler-SR2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-dependencies.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    ...

    <!-- TODO The version of this dependency lets Spring Boot fail, but is 
        necessary tu run the old backend -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-iostreams</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ...

</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>verify</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            ...
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-config-zip</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/config.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <finalName>configs</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-dist-zip</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
                        <finalName>...</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <requireJavaVersion>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                    </requireJavaVersion>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>attach-standalone</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>standalone</shadedClassifierName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dont-attach-standalone</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Prevent huge shaded artifacts from being deployed to Artifactory -->
                        <outputFile>...</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

> EDIT: I just found out that if you remove the version element inside of the conflicting dependency the Spring Boot Application works, but unfortunately the backend then fails.

Comment: Just to verify that your assumption is correct about the conflicting logging package, can you exclude the `spring-boot-admin-starter-server` in the pom file? We just want to eliminate some dependencies to isolate an issue and find out the cause. You don't really need `spring-boot-admin-starter-server` to make the project a spring boot.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that I do not inherit from the Spring Boot Starter in `<parent>`, because the parent is occupied by another unit that the old backend inherits from. If I run the Spring app without the `spring-boot-admin-starter-server` I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 SpringApplication cannot be resolved

 at ...restAdapter.RestfulServerLauncher.main(RestfulServerLauncher.java:10)`

Comment: You have to make the spring boot app works without your backend dependencies. Then add one at a time the dependencies and make it run and check if something breaks. Can you share the pom file?

Comment: First of all. thanks for your help. ;) As stated above the spring boot app runs perfectly fine as long as I comment out the conflicting dependency. Like you suggested I have added the backend dependencies one at a time. That's what led me to the conclusion that the logging dependency has to be the source of the problem. I will provide the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, but that's probably not the best way to do it:

I just replaced the `<spring-boot-dependencies.version>2.0.4</spring-boot-dependencies.version>` with an older version that is compatible with the conflicting logging dependency, namely version `1.4.7.RELEASE`.

This is the latest version at which both the Spring Boot application and the backend are working simultaneously (found that out by try-and-error).

Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Cheers